# WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 - Tomcat 8

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, websocket

Context:

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2014/02/hazelcast-websockets.html) - that allows us to integrate Hazelcast with Websockets capabilities. I am using eclipse and tomcat 8.

Unfortunately my client cannot to the websocket and the error is throwing is:

[image: websocket error]

After investigating a little bit the existing stackoverflow questions related to this problem I suspect there is a problem with the websocket implementation in Apache Tomcat 8.

My websocket dependecy in maven looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My socket class look like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/stocks")
public class StockWebSocket implements EntryListener<String, StockRecord> {
```

And the client connects like this:

```
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8080/hazelcast-web/stocks";
console.log("CONNECT CALLED");
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.onopen = function(event) {
    onOpen(event)
};
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: What does the Tomcat logs say? Did the hazelcast-web WAR deploy correctly?